# Use JS Template as Rails Partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ejs

I have a rails 4 app where I have some Javascript that generates a .jst.ejs template that looks like:

```
<!--name.jst.ejs which is in assets/javascripts/templates-->
<input type="text" name="store[name]" placeholder="Store Name" />
```

then I have a rails partial ( called _name.html.erb in my views directory) that looks like:

```
<input type='text' name="store[name]" value="<%= @store.name%>" />
```

What I'm trying to do is to keep this DRY, and only have to use the one ejs file (instead of having basically a duplicated .ejs and .erb file).

Is there a way to:

1. Call an ejs file as a rails partial: eg something like: `<%= render "name" %>` (which renders the name.jst.ejs file?
2. Also, because the two files are somewhat different, is there a way to differentiate the code if it was rendered as ejs vs erb? For example, something like:

`<input type='text' name="store[name]" <% if erb %> value="<%= @store.name %>" <% else %> placeholder="Store Name" <% end %> />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try something like:

   `<%= render "name.jst.ejs", :formats => [:erb], isErb: true %>`
2. Then in the partial, check if isErb is present